# How could I use nginx to load balance RabbitMQ?

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, load-balancing

The web application that we are working on uses RabbitMQ for message queuing. I am trying to setup an nginx server to use as a load balancer. This is my set up and progress so far.

**Server 1**

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- RabbitMQ node
- nginx

**Server 2**

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- RabbitMQ node (cluster from Server 1)

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream rabbitmq {
        server server1:5672;
        server server2:5672;
    }

    server {
        listen       5054;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://rabbitmq;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }    
}
```

In the application's config file, the RabbitMQ configure is as follows:

```
<RabbitMqConfiguration hostName="server1" virtualHost="/" port="-1" userName="user" password="pass" useRabbitMqPersistence="true" publisherTimeout="00:01:00" />
```

This is my first setting up nginx and RabbitMQ so there's a good chance I might have configured something wrong. Any advice and assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: do you find solution?